# Show that $a^{\log_c b}= b^{\log_c a}$

Tags: logarithms

Show that $a^{\log_c b}= b^{\log_c a}$.

I start from LHS and add $\log a$ on it, but it leave $\log_c b$. Then I have not idea about how to continue it(maybe my working is wrong...

Can anybody solve this question?

Comment: Take $\log_c$ of both sides.

Comment: Do you mean $a^{\log_c b} = b^{\log_c a}$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the format

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 3):

Let $\displaystyle\log_cb=B\implies c^B=b$

and $\displaystyle\log_ca=A\implies c^A=a$

$\displaystyle\implies b^{\log_ca}=b^A=(c^B)^A=(c^A)^B=a^{\log_cb}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\log_cb=\dfrac{\ln b}{\ln c}$ and $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$